# How can we get the delta of members for custom directory roles in Azure AD / Entra Id

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I created a custom role in Entra ID and followed below steps:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Not I am trying to list out the directory roles using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRole/delta` but it does not detect it.

I thought, the custom role was not activated by default and tried activating the custom roles using

```html
POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles 
Content-type: application/json

{
  "roleTemplateId": "fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1"
}
```

but getting error saying
`{ "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "Could not resolve request to a valid role template. A valid value must be specified for 'displayName' or 'roleTemplateId'.", "details": [ { "code": "PropertyRequired", "message": "Could not resolve request to a valid role template. A valid value must be specified for 'displayName' or 'roleTemplateId'.", "target": "roleTemplateId" } ], "innerError": { "date": "2023-11-24T04:18:34", "request-id": "c2ff8f89-a856-4e53-b0ec-a6d80c7437fd", "client-request-id": "c2ff8f89-a856-4e53-b0ec-a6d80c7437fd" } } }`

I would highly appreciate any help. Need to detect the custom roles and delta of directory objects being assigned to custom roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom role:

[image]

Added assignments to the custom role:

[image]

**To fetch the custom roles created**, use the below Microsoft query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=(isBuiltIn+eq+false)
```

[image]

Use the **`id`** or the **`templateId`** of the custom role and fetch the directory objects assigned to custom roles:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '1eeb2565-876b-4b8b-81d5-****'
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to do an incremental listing of custom roles which means any changes in roles and any member this role is getting assigned to.
With the above API, we will always get full data

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: So, I have a requirement to back up the changes only to avoid unnecessary storage costs. If I use the  /directoryRoles endpoint, I get the activated standard roles and delta of members. However since the API does not return the custom roles, any member the custom role is assigned to will not be detected as part of this API call. One option we have is to get all custom roles every time and then all the current members but that defeats the purpose of incremental. I was looking if there is a way to get delta for custom roles as well like standard roles.

Comment: AFAIK the endpoint doesn't support delta.

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom role, you can [list it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roledefinitions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) through the endpoint

```
GET /v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions
```

with filter to get only custom role

```
GET /v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions?$filter=isBuiltIn eq false
```

The endpoint doesn't support delta

To list users assigned to custom role

```
GET /v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$expand=principal&$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '{custom-role-id}'
```

You can expand `principal` to get info about users assigned to a role